# AJAX and URL rewriting

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an htaccess file (apache server) and I'm doing the following url rewriting :

```
RewriteRule questionnaire/adminpassword questionnaire/change_admin_password.php
```

in my javascript file I was doing the AJAX call as following :

```
 $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       cache:false,
       url: 'change_admin_password.php',
       data: {'currentPassword':currentPassword, 'newPassword': newPassword},
       dataType: 'html',
       success:function(response){
        alert(response);              
       },
      error:function(){
      alert("error");
      }
   });
```

I changed the url in the ajax call to :  `url: 'adminpassword',`  but now the call reloads the page and get its content instead of running the php script on the server and giving the response. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: You get the same problem if you make it a `GET` request?

Comment: yes same issue with Get

Answer (score 0):

You know that if you just use 'adminpassword' you gonna get a relative path. Make sure the current path is the right one, otherwise use the full path, possibly 'questionnaire/adminpassword'

Try accessing the URL directly. Type it in the browser. What do you get? Are you getting the expected response? Then inspect the actual request made by the ajax call using a tool like chrome dev tools or firebug. Is the request hitting the right URL?

If you are hitting the right URL, the problem is probably in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I think I know what is happening here and this might help others in future

When you use `questionnaire/adminpassword` your .htaccess file translates it to `questionnaire/change_admin_password.php` and am guessing you are redirecting all request hitting your site to an index.php file in your root folder which processes url and requires the particular file adding to it the header and footer, its no different when ajax requests are made.

To avoid redirecting to the index file that processes the file you can avoid this totally by allowing direct access to a particular folder in your .htaccess file like so

`Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/api` where api is the folder those scripts called by javascript are located